I have a line of vertexes on a mesh that I would to linearly interpolate the Z position of
I have a grid like mesh (pictured).  At one edge I have a vertex at pos z=1.  Further along the loop running in the x direction I have a vertex that I want to be at pos z=3.27 (actual values are arbitrary).  Is there a way to select a line of vertexes and get Blender to linearly interpolate between the two positions at either end of the line so I have a smoothly rising set of vertexes without me having to manually select each vertex and set every z-pos by hand?


You can select the vertices, with shift, select the one that should be at Z = 0 last (this will be the "active" element).
Set your pivot point to active element.

Use the "shear" command (it's on the right click menu, and it's shift+ctrl+alt+s), or, alternatively, the "rotation" followed by some "scale".
Select an axis and gogogo.

You can also use the Gstretch command from the LoopTools addon.

Cool, that seems exactly what I want.  How do I precisely set the end point when using the shear?  In my specific case my active point is at z=-0.812679 and I want the end point to be at z=-0.855725.  Doing shift+ctrl+alt+s y -0.043046 did not move the points as I expected

The end point is the active element, (the last selected point, the one that has a different highlight from the others)

I meant "precisely set the z-position of the opposite end of the line from the active element"
The shear operation seems to be performing some relative operation so I can't work out how "much" to apply to precisely position my gradient.
I suppose it would be simpler to just work out the correct angle and use rotation instead,

I know this is not ideal, but you can scale them in z and type 0 (flat line), then you can type their  base Z in the properties. Do the shear. Then get a calculator, divide your target z by the current Z of the target point. Scale in Z and type that value. @AlistairHutton
